# Limit displayed item / menu height in floating context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu

Is there any way to make to limit the height of a floating context menu (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu the one on the left)? I want to make it scrollable after a fixed number of items instead of making it fill the whole page and then become scrollable.